# Add an onBlur to all form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So on a specific page I have some number of form elements, anywhere between 3 and 8, depending upon the user and their action on the page.

How can I add a specific onblur event to all of the form elements dynamically on the page?

If I have:

```
function doThisOnBlur() { stuff }
```

How can I add that same function to all of these once the page loads.  No elements are created after the page loads but different elements may appear for different users.

```
<input type="text" id="x">
<input type="text" id="y">
<select id="z">...</select>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Specific as unique to each element? On the fly as in on dynamically created elements?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Edit:* For updated question
Use [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and an anonymous function for this (doesn't matter how many elements there are):

```
$(":input").blur(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

If you need to bind certain functions to certain fields, use classes or an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) on name, anything to distinguish them...if the selector doesn't find an element it simply won't bind an event handler to anything.  That way, the same overall code works for *all* users, even if they only see *some* of the form elements available.

---

*For original question*: if elements were dynamically added after page-load.
I think [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to capture the `blur` event is what you're after here, using [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) as the selector:

```
$(":input").live('blur', function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: or `$(":input").blur(function(){ .. });`  Live watches the page for future elements, and that's not really needed if he's not adding elements after the page loads. Both will work though.

Comment: @Jim - The question was edited to clarify after I posted this answer, I'll update to include his edit.

Answer (score 10):

Without jQuery:

```
function doThisOnBlur(){
// your fancy code
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    inputs[i].onblur = doThisOnBlur;
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++)
    selects[i].onblur = doThisOnBlur;
```

I made it the simplest as I could. I'd refactor that and don't assign event handlers this way, but I pointed to answer your question.

Comment: if you want Dynamic Element Binding then i would use jQuery:live to do this, they have pretty much got this feature down to a tee!

Comment: Don't know why i written that, i should of checked your name and realise that you posted an answer not a question :/ sorry

Comment: @Nick: I think I understood well the question from the scratch, although it was not so clear. :) .. However, that would not be my answer if I saw the jquery tag there before.    
@RobbertPitt: No problem!

Comment: @NickCraver just as in this answer... `d=document.createElement("input");d.onblur=doThisOnBlur;`